# In distillation at what stage does purification happen?

Tags: distillation

A novice question: is it purified during evaporation or elsewhere? I’m getting a water distiller for drinking water after re-adding minerals for health reasons. I described how it works to my son. He postulated that the tube where the condensation happens will get full of contaminants and will produce dirty water that’s  bad to drink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no information to decide if the son's statement is true or not.

Evaporation strips water from all nonvolatile components. But since its condensation, it can get new ones.

For more, details of specific scenario is needed, including guaranteed purity of minerals.

Generally, distillation to make drinkable water is overkill, economically and energetically.

Answer (score 0):

With distilling, "purification" will depend on the boiling point of the water compared with whatever else is in the pot.  You can measure the temperature of the vapor before it goes into the condenser.  Water vapor will be around 100 C or 212 F.

If you are distilling from a salt solution or hard water, everything else will stay in the "pot". That's what will need to be cleaned occasionally ("scale" can be cleaned off with vinegar).

The condenser should remain clean.  To be sure, throw away what comes out of it at first, and keep the rest.  Try not to let your pot get completely evaporated.  It may get too hot if everything boils off.

If there is any chance other volatiles are in the water, such as alcohol or benzene, they will be boiled off and condensed too, contaminating your "distilled" water.  In that case your son is right and distillation will not reliably purify the water.